# Output dictionary where each element is a string's character with an index

Tags: python

> UPD: inserting `from collections import OrderedDict` into one of my code cells helped

I want to make a program which accepts a string and then outputs dictionary where each element is this string's character with an index.

**Input:** `hello`

**Output** `{'h': 1, 'e': 2, 'l': 3, 'l': 4, 'o': 5}`

I've come up with several ways to create this kind of dictionary. However, in every case I have the following output with above-mentioned input: `{'e': 2, 'h': 1, 'l': 4, 'o': 5}`

```
#solution 1
s = str(input())
dic = {}
for index, symb in enumerate(s, 1):
  dic[symb]=index
dic

#soultion 2
s = input()
d4 = {}
d4 = dict(zip(s,range(1,len(s)+1)))
d4
```

What can be an issue here? I will appreciate any help. THanks in advance.

P.S. for coding I use Google Collab

Comment: `{'h': 1, 'e': 2, 'l': 3, 'l': 4, 'o': 5}` is not correct. You cannot have duplicates in dict keys ('l' in your case)

Comment: Also dictionaries are not ordered, so you would not see letters in the iteration order of the string

Comment: @OneCricketeer See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: @Barmar Old habits die hard :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries only allow for one value per key, therefore there won't be two values for the key `l`, no matter how hard you try. Also, dictionaries are unordered, so the items won't appear in the order they were inserted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Simple and Easy:-
    v_str='hello'
    class Dictlist(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self[key]
        except KeyError:
            super(Dictlist, self).__setitem__(key, [])
        self[key].append(value)

p_dict=Dictlist()
for i, j in enumerate(v_str):
    p_dict[j]=i
print(p_dict)

# output:-{'h': [0], 'e': [1], 'l': [2, 3], 'o': [4]}
```

Comment: Your solution would have the same results that the OP was getting originally.

Comment: Dictionary doesn't have duplicate keys :)  Adding another answer might be helpful

Comment: I failed to notice that you were adding them into lists, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

As @IoaTzimas points out correctly in the comments is that you have fundamental misunderstanding of how `dict` keys work. `dict` keys must be unique (think like a house key) because the key maps to the value.